# best way to deal huge request in WCF

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, design-patterns, concurrency

Best approach of WCF service for handling huge request like 10k request at a time.
Please suggest.

**Edit:**

Let me clear, I have approx 10k hardware devices which connect through the ethernet. Now I have to communicate from the devices.So what is the best way to handle this situation in WCF.

Comment: Are you asking about the number of requests per second is 10k or the size of the transfer returned is 10k?

Comment: not per second but may be in 15/20 minutes.

Comment: Answers are on hold, but depending on your hardware, you may be OK with a Single Web/App server depending on how fast the rest of the components in the stack are.  Performance is always tricky, as you always have to understand where the problem is.  For example, if your maxed out on CPU in the Web or App tier, you can install a load balancer and expand the hardware to handle that many requests. If your database is slow in responding, are you using connection pools, do you need more disks, more memory, etc..  You need to measure performance on each tier and add where you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the problem is and what the content is. It also depends on whether it is the transfer of 10k (which shouldn't take long on a fast connection) or if it is the creation of the result.

Let's assume it is the data transfer.

**Compression**

You could try to enable GZip compression ([WCF Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458(v=vs.110).aspx)) to see if that would speed things up. Be aware that there is some overhead in doing the actual compression and decompression.

**Streaming**

Not sure if this would speed things up ([WCF Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx)).

**Bulk fetching**

If possible you could get you data in chunks and then on the client start up multiple threads/Tasks for retrieving different chunks of the data and then put it all together when all threads are done. This could also speed things up if the problem is actually data creation.

Comment: ,See the edit part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with huge request, take data as request.

for that you need to change the readerquotas.
beacuse WCF by default gets only 8192 characters.
so u need to change the readerquotas.

example:

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```